# Running Testrpc and truffle from powershell not working

Tags: powershell, ethereum, truffle, consensys-truffle

I was installing some modules/packages needed for Ethereum development and I previously installed truffle and testrpc, and I could run them fine from PowerShell. I am now suddenly unable to run either as it says 'testrpc' is not recognised as a cmdlet, and 'truffle' is not recognised as a cmdlet. I would appreciate some help on how/why this happened and how to fix it. I also tried restarting my device but that did not help.
[Error produced when I run the script/command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmreL.png)

Comment: Could you post the command you're trying and also a copy of said error message in aid of people attempting to help you diagnose the issue?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you I have amended it.

Comment: How did you install _truffle_ and _testrpc_, was this through chocolatey?When you say you previously had them installed, how long ago?

Comment: Yes I installed them through chocolatey via powershell.

Comment: Correction I installed them via npm not choco, I installed nodejs ,git and visual studio code via choco.

Answer (score 0):

If it was working alright previously, uninstalling and reinstalling truffle should work.
npm uninstall -g truffle
npm install -g truffle

In case this does not work, below will work.

```
run npm init #this will make a new npm project particularly package.json
run npm i truffle #this will download node modules 
run ./node_modules/.bin/truffle init #this will create a truffle project
```